# Show notification badge when MacOS application is in foreground

Tags: swift, macos

Is there a way to force **MacOS** notification badges to appear when the app is in foreground?

I know it's an Apple standard to keep the badge in the notification center when the app window is active. But is there a way to force the badge to show up? I saw that is possible for iOS with `UNUserNotificationCenter`, but is it possible to do something like this for MacOS apps?